# valueHasMutated not working as expected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to force a UI update on modifying a value of an object in an `observableArray`, but the objects in the array aren't `observable`. I assumed you could do this with `valueHasMutated`, but it isn't working as I expected.

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/g7d5e7yb/2/) if I click the update button nothing happens, but if I manually reset the array it updates:

```html
<div id="bindings">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: observableThings">
    <li data-bind="text: id"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: updateValue">Update</button>
<button data-bind="click: forceUpdate">Force Update</button>
```

```js
var things = [
  { id: 1, thing: false },  
  { id: 2, thing: false },
  { id: 3, thing: false },
  { id: 4, thing: false }
]

var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.observableThings = ko.observableArray(things);

  self.updateValue = function() {
    self.observableThings()[0].id = 5;
    self.observableThings.valueHasMutated();
  }

  self.forceUpdate = function() {
    self.observableThings()[0].id = 5;
    var origThings = self.observableThings();
    self.observableThings(null);
    self.observableThings(origThings);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

How is `valueHasMutated` supposed to work?

Answer (score 6):

Sticking a bunch of plain objects into an observable array does not magically make the properties of those objects observable.

An observable array generally only observes item removal and item insertion. If the items themselves have properties you want to observe then these properties *explicitly* need to be made observable.

The [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) can help with that. It can do a few very nice things, do read the documentation page.

```js
function ListOfThings(params) {
  var self = this;

  self.things = ko.observableArray();

  self.updateValue = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.things(), function (thing) {
      thing.id( ~~(Math.random() * 100) );
    });
  }

  // init
  ko.mapping.fromJS(params, {}, self);
}


var vm = new ListOfThings({
  things: [
    { id: 1, thing: false },  
    { id: 2, thing: false },
    { id: 3, thing: false },
    { id: 4, thing: false }
  ]
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div id="bindings">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: things">
    <li data-bind="text: id"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: updateValue">Update</button>

<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

---

**EDIT** You seem to be disproportionally fixed on `valueHasMutated` and the impossibility of using the mapping plugin. The mapping plugin is helpful, but it's certainly not necessary.

```js
function Thing(params) {
    this.id =  ko.observable(params.id);
    this.thing = ko.observable(params.thing);
}

function ListOfThings(params) {
  var self = this;

  self.things = ko.observableArray();

  self.updateValue = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.things(), function (thing) {
      thing.id( ~~(Math.random() * 100) );
    });
  }

  // init
  self.things(ko.utils.arrayMap(params.things, function (obj) {
      return new Thing(obj);
  }));
}


var vm = new ListOfThings({
  things: [
    { id: 1, thing: false },  
    { id: 2, thing: false },
    { id: 3, thing: false },
    { id: 4, thing: false }
  ]
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="bindings">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: things">
    <li data-bind="text: id"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: updateValue">Update</button>

<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: I didn't want to use the mapping plugin as we're doing it in typescript and that means changing a lot of code. I don't see how this answers the question at all as the word `valueHasMutated` doesn't appear in your answer at all, which is what the question is about.

Comment: The word `valueHasMutated` does not appear in this answer because you don't need it. You are simply doing it wrong. The core point of my answer is: You need to make everything observable *explicitly* that you want to observe. The mapping plugin only automates that step, you don't need to use it.

Comment: @mattmanser Also: This post answers your question in the only meaningful way: The code does what you want to happen. Run the snippet and see it working. It really don't understand how this justifies a downvote.

Comment: @Tomalak - Vote up. Completely agree with you - the using observable properties is the better (and natural for KO) way for UI updating.

Comment: @mattmanser Are you even reading what I am writing? You don't need to use the mapping plugin, for Christ's sake. **You are using Knockout wrong, that's why your code does not work.** Trying to use `valueHasMutated` is the wrong thing to do, it won't work, and I am running out of ways to put it. Make the properties of the items in that array observable and everything will start to work.

Comment: Because I can't! I asked a specific technical question, you're answering a different question with a generic, non-technical answer, the equivalent of 'rewrite everything'. You don't even mention the function I'm asking about in your answer, which shows you don't understand the question. I simply cannot do what you're saying, I don't know how else to put this, your answer is wrong. It's wrong and it's not an answer to the question I asked. Just delete it. I'm appreciate you spent time on it, but you're simply not answering the question asked. And becoming very insulting.

Comment: I certainly won't delete the single correct answer to your question. You have asked "Why is this not working?" and I showed you how to do it correctly. *"How can I use `valueHasMutated` to make it work?"* is a red herring and a completely pointless distraction. You shouldn't even try to do that, it will never work, it is the wrong way to do it. You can't honestly expect from me that I show you how to do it wrongly. I show you how to do it correctly, that's why I am here. You can't seem to let go of this obsession with `valueHasMutated`, and that's your main issue here.

Comment: I spelt it out for you how to do it in accordance with Knockout's design, without dirty hacks or force and without the mapping plugin. See modified answer.

Comment: Sorry for digging up old question but wouldn't be easier to create separate model for data stored in observableArray, and make properties observable as well? I'm relatively new to KO but for me is natural solution especially when using TypeScript.

Comment: Easier... not really. Because then you would have to create a separate viewmodel first. And as long as that viewmodel is nothing but a "glorified observable container" (so to speak) with no own behavior or API, it is basically useless to have it at all. Making a plain object with observable properties would be less work, but of course it also carries less semantic value. Considering you come from a TypeScript point of view, I can see why you would prefer a separate viewmodel, though.

Answer (score 2):

KnockoutJS code (thanks to debugger version in your fiddle), executing on valueHasMutated leads to

```
evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection: function (notifyChange) {
// some other code
// ...

// newValue is the same as state.latestValue => "computedObservable["notifySubscribers"]" is not called
        if (computedObservable.isDifferent(state.latestValue, newValue)) {
            if (!state.isSleeping) {
                computedObservable["notifySubscribers"](state.latestValue, "beforeChange");
            }

            state.latestValue = newValue;

            if (state.isSleeping) {
                computedObservable.updateVersion();
            } else if (notifyChange) {
                computedObservable["notifySubscribers"](state.latestValue);
            }
        }
```

This can do the trick:

```
  self.updateValue = function() {
    var index = 0;
    var item = self.observableThings()[index];
    // Update item content
    item.id = 5;
    // Force array to update markup
    self.observableThings.splice(index, 1);
    self.observableThings.splice(index, 0, item);
  }
```

But IMHO the better way is to use observable properties.

Comment: How's this different from my hack? This is just another hack by modifying the array.

Comment: Your hack forces recreation of all markup displaying your array. My approach will update markup only for one (changed) item.

Comment: @mattmanser my answer shows - why valueHasMutated does not work in your case and proposes working solution with minimal markup changes. Why downvoted?

Comment: Because it's not an answer to the question! I need all the items updated anyway so your hack is actually worse than mine. Hence the d/v.

Answer (score 2):

`valueHasMutated` would typically be used if you wanted to change the contents of a large observableArray multiple times but only trigger a single change notification and a single UI update or whatever. So you would operate on the underlying array and then call `valueHasMutated` when all your changes are complete.

The reason that your call to `valueHasMutated` isn't doing anything is because the 'value' of the observable array (meaning the items in it, not the properties of those items) has not changed. Your call causes a re-evaluation of the state of the array - have any items been added or removed? The answer is no, so no change notification happens.

If you want to make your code work with the smallest change possible, you need to swap in a new item rather than just update one of the properties on an existing item.

```
self.updateValue = function() {
    var newVal = { id: 5, thing: false };
    self.observableThings()[0] = newVal;
    self.observableThings.valueHasMutated();
  }
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ka0fvbj4/)

The final thing to say is that kind of the case I outlined above (i.e. updating many members of an array yet only triggering a sigle UI update) is really the only reason that you should be 'forcing' change notifications to happen. If you're having to do something like this then you've gone wrong and saying 'but I'll have to re-write loads of code' is never a good reason not to do it properly.

Comment: *"'but I'll have to re-write loads of code' is never a good reason not to do it properly"* Thank you. The OP's misunderstanding of Knockout is already apparent in the naming he chose for the array: "`observableThings`" implies he thinks the things are observable while they are not. Unfortunately it does not seem as if he would listen to reason, which is a bit disappointing.