# Why are the replaced values in ko.ObservableArray not updating my view?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm trying to make an overview page for a simple webshop. The client can go to the next page, but this will not reload the whole document, it just triggers a fetch for the next set of products.
I'm filling the list of elements with knockout. The website is loaded with an empty list of products, and an initial fetch is started. This is currently done with an constant value, but in the future will depend on the URL.

After the fetch is done the value of the ObservableArray is updated, but the view doesn't change. If I bind the viewmodel after the fetch, then it will update the view accordingly, but I think that that is not the preferred method.

I think the problem lies in my understanding of the conventions of the library. I was hoping someone could make it more clear to me.

My code is as follows:

```js
let OverviewModel = function() {
    let self = this;

    self.products = ko.observableArray([]);
};

let OverviewController = function(model) {
    let self = this;

    ko.applyBindings(model);
    console.log("Model is bound"); // Prints

    self.fetchProducts = function (amount, page) {
        let url = new URL("/webshop/products", window.location.href)
        url.searchParams.append("amount", amount)
        url.searchParams.append("page", page)
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            console.log(model.products()); // Prints: []
            model.products.removeAll();
            ko.utils.arrayPushAll(model.products, data);
            model.products.valueHasMutated();
            console.log(model.products()) // Prints: [Object { title: Lorem, ... }, ...]
        });
    };
};

let model = new OverviewModel();
let controller = new OverviewController(model);
controller.fetchProducts(20, 0);
```

Comment: This question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618682/valuehasmutated-not-working-as-expected) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

not really sure what's not working for you, see this snippet where everything is working as expected. I've removed some code inside the fetchProducts because this is not how a straightforward knockout update should go. (and a little fake api promise for the data retrieval)

```js
const getProducts = (amount, page) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (isNaN(Number(amount)) || isNaN(Number(page))) {
      reject(new Error('Products not found'));
    } 
    setTimeout(() => resolve(['foo', 'bar']), 500);
  });

let OverviewModel = function() {
  let self = this;

  self.products = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.products.subscribe(products => console.log(products));
};

let OverviewController = function(model) {
  let self = this;

  ko.applyBindings(model);
  console.log("Model is bound"); // Prints

  self.fetchProducts = (amount, page) => getProducts(amount, page).then(data => {    
    model.products(data);
  });
};

let model = new OverviewModel();
let controller = new OverviewController(model);
controller.fetchProducts(20, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.products, as: 'product' }">
  <li data-bind="text: product"></li>
</ul>
```